# Grep SPAM tagged message in mailbox

Tags: regex, linux, grep, spam

Hello everybody i need some help with ...
I must clean (delete) **spam message** from many mailboxes so I must **find it**. Messages are tagged in subject by different antispam tools so there are some tags like SPAM, [SPAM], ***SPAM*** etc. So I must find all messages tagged with this "keywords".

Sample subject is: ***SPAM*** Buy viagra

I know grep -l for file names and grep -E or egrep for regex.

```
grep -E "^Subject: \[SPAM\]"
grep -E "^Subject: \*\*\*SPAM\*\*\*"
grep -E "^Subject: \*\*\*\ SPAM\ \*\*\*" # (1 space before and after SPAM word)
```

How to put togeter working in one line?
I used grep with alternation "|" like

```
"^Subject: (\[SPAM\]|\*\*\*SPAM\*\*\*|\*\*\*\ SPAM\ \*\*\*)"
```

but isn't working good.

There is one message in one file, so many files equal many messages. The content of files is like:

```
From: Sender <sender@domain.com>
To: Receiver <receiver@mailbox.com>
Subject: *** SPAM *** Buy viagra on-line
```

**So I only need grep in Subject row. That's all.**

Comment: That won't delete anything though, so you might want to include more information about what your end result is supposed to be.

Comment: I've edited my post - only how to grep spam in subject, I don't need ready-to-use script :-)

Comment: Could you explicitly state format of the mailboxes? [mailbox file (many messages in single file), maildir, mh folder] Which scripting language do you prefer? [perl, python]

Comment: Add a list with examples for vaild input strings.

Comment: I've edited again my post.

Comment: That looks a lot like SpamAssassin.  Maybe you'd prefer to search for `X-Spam-Flag: YES` in the headers. You can this do with `grep -Fx "X-Spam-Flag: YES"` which will do a plain-text full-line search (which will be faster than any query via regex, though that won't matter unless you're diving through gigs+ of data).

Answer (score 0):

A general regex would be -

```
^Subject:\W*SPAM(?:\W|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should work:

```
grep -E '^Subject: [* []+SPAM[] *]+'
```

By using a character class it eliminates the need for using `|` OR statements.

**Input:**

```
Subject: [SPAM]
Subject: SPAM         // shouldn't match
Subject: ***SPAM***
Subject: *** SPAM ***
Subject: Not Spam     // shouldn't match
Subject: ** SPAM **
```

**Output:**

```
Subject: [SPAM]
Subject: ***SPAM***
Subject: *** SPAM ***
Subject: ** SPAM **
```